# Magento product list with custom productCollection

Tags: php, magento

For my module I need to create a custom productCollection built with various addAttributeToFilter modifiers. However, I have no idea how to get such a collection into a product list like the default magento one.
So basicly I'd like to create a pre-filtered product list, could anyone give me some advice on how to start such a thing?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I can make the collection, just not show it like the default product list.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of struggling I found a solution:
I overrided Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List and made my own _getProductCollection with:

```
$collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute', array('operator' => 'value'));
/* more filters go here */
$this->_productCollection = $collection;
return $this->_productCollection;
```

This seemed to be the only way to get the original product list working without any errors or category problems.

With thanks to Guerra!!

Answer (score 2):

use this in list.phtml:

```
$_productCollection->clear()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('eq' => 63))
        ->load();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter();
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Yes that part goes well, but how do I get it in a list like the default magento product list? Can I override the default one somehow?

Comment: No in the frontend, same as the product list of a category.

Comment: If you want change the default product category list load, you need change Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List this file. But i'm not sure about what you need. The Category product list its the same as all list on the Magento. The only difference its the way what it is showed on the screen.

Comment: My module pre-filters and generates a custom productCollection. And I prefer to show it in the frontend just like any other category (but with my custom productCollection of course)

Comment: You can do by 2 ways, you can extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List, and subscribe _getProductCollection method to return your custom collection list. Or go to list.phtml on Catalog/Product, and there you call your module/model -> getcustomcollection(), and set it up to $_productCollection.

Comment: I guess I'm going to override the template using an observer, thanks